# Происхождение слова "околеть"

Tags: этимология

Внезапно задумалась над этим словом. Интересно, оно произошло от слова "кол"?
Причем, употребляется ведь оно и в значении **замерзнуть**, и в значении **умереть**. Однако последнее — только по отношению к животным (почему-то).

Comment: Проблемы этимологии возникают из-за того, что этим вопросом занимаются узкие специалисты в области языкознания. Зачастую нужны знания из иных наук. Слово "околеть" применялось только к животным. Если "околевал" человек, то тем самым выражалось пренебрежение к умершему. Когда четвероногое животное умирает, то оно падает набок. При этом голова животного обычно склоняется ближе к передним ногам, а сами ноги своими концами собираются в одном месте. Спина животного

Comment: Спина умершего животного становится более выпуклой, а хвост загибается в сторону собранных вместе ног. Таким образом, силуэт тела умершего животного становится более округлым, чем при жизни. Животное округляется - животное околевает. Слово "околевать" происходит от слова "коло", т.е. "круг". Недавно видел на дороге дохлую мышь. Она действительно околела.

Answer (score 3):

"Околеть" происходит от слова "кол" - сделаться застывшим, твердым, как кол. "Кол" - от слова "колоть" (буквально то, что отколото от дерева).

Answer (score 2):

Я бы чуть дополнил, если позволите.
"Околеть" по отношению к животным появилось в связи с физиологической особенностью трупа утрачивать гибкость, даже при плюсовых температурах. Ткани деревенеют, остывшее тело становится твердым и не меняет свою форму даже при перемещении, как деревянный кол. Само собой, для использования в пищу (да и для обработки) такая туша животного не годится.
В примере @Софии значение слова "кол", пожалуй, не совсем удачное: "околеть" — стать подобным колу, длинной прямой палке, зачастую заостренной, которой можно **наколоть**, проткнуть.
А "колоть", например, дрова — это чуть другая история, так как это можно делать только с твердыми предметами.
Для сравнения: более мягкие, не подверженные раскалыванию, предметы приходится **резать** или **рубить**.

Answer (score 0):

> Кол, колода, кольцо, коловорот...

Околица — укладывается в древнеславянское происхождение от слова `коло — круг`, символизирующего солнце.
Но вот глаголы `колоть` и `околеть` ставят меня в тупик, хотя, возможно, они более поздние производные от того же *кола*. 
Ведь раньше не говорили `колоть`, говорили `бить`, применительно к чурбаку:

> бить баклуши —- колоть заготовки для ложек

и

> разить —

применительно к тому, чтобы уколоть кого-нибудь, к примеру, копьем.

Answer (score 0):

ОКОЛЕТЬ имеет в корне слово КОЛО — круг.
Но в данном случае не круг солнца или какой-то твёрдый кол, а круг вращения рождения и смерти.
Известно, что древние русичи верили в реинкарнацию.
Слово КОЛОТЬ (дрова) означает делать взмахи топором, описывающие круг.

Слово КОЛОТЬ (в смысле укалывать) лишь указывает, что действие совершается посредством КОЛа — узкого круглого предмета.
КОЛ — ось, вокруг которой совершается вращение: движение по кругу. Да и сам он имеет на срезе форму круга.

Сходные слова: КОЛодец, КОЛун, КОЛесо, КОЛбаса, КОЛокол, КОЛоворот, КАЛендарь, КАЛач, КАЛанча...
Трифонема КАЛ — КОЛ имеет ещё несколько значений, *кроме вращения,* но это тема другого разговора.

Answer (score 0):

Проблемы этимологии возникают из-за того, что этим вопросом занимаются узкие специалисты в области языкознания. Зачастую нужны знания из иных наук.
Слово "околеть" применялось только к животным. Если "околевал" человек, то тем самым выражалось пренебрежение к умершему. Когда четвероногое животное умирает, то оно падает на бок. При этом голова животного обычно склоняется ближе к передним ногам, а сами ноги своими концами собираются в одном месте.
Спина умершего животного становится более выпуклой, а хвост загибается в сторону собранных вместе ног.
Именно таким образом силуэт тела умершего животного становится более округлым, чем при жизни. Животное округляется — животное околевает.
Слово "околевать" происходит от слова "коло", т.е. "круг". Недавно видел на дороге дохлую мышь. Она действительно *околела*.